# javascript function execution sequence

Tags: javascript

I have a question about javascript function sequence,I have two code below,Why the different results of these two programs?
I think first program result will equal to second program result.

```
function test1() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
  }
  console.log("test1");
}

function test2() {
  console.log("test2");
}

test1();
test2();
//test1
//test2
```

---

```
function test1() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("test1");
      }, 1000);
    }

function test2() {
  console.log("test2");
}

test1();
test2();
//test2
//test1
```

Comment: running a loop is sync, `setTimeout` is async, that's the difference

Answer (score 0):

Because the purpose of `setTimeout` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) | [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout)) is to schedule a call to a function **later**, asynchronously. So in your second example, you call `test1` first, and it schedules a call to the anonymous callback for a second later, then returns. Then you call `test2` which prints immediately. A second later, the callback is called by the timer, and prints `test1`.

Perhaps this small tweak to your second example will make it clearer:

```js
function test1() {
  console.log("test1 called, setting up timer");
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("timer fired and called the callback");
  }, 1000);
}

function test2() {
  console.log("test2 called");
}

test1();
test2();
```

You see this output (the last line only appears after a second):

```
test1 called, setting up timer
test2 called
timer fired and called the callback
```

Answer (score 0):

[**setTimeout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) is an asynchronous operation , the number is use to define delay at which the code will execute. `1000` is the delay, so you are seeing the result differently

Answer (score 0):

http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval
check this out
mabe it will help :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, maybe your current thread got stuck in the "for" loop in your first code snippet. But the operation is asynchronously done in the second code snippet.